# WordPress installation on VPS -is not loading CSS on domain, only on IP address

Tags: php, wordpress, dns

I tried to install WordPress on my VPS machine running Ubuntu 16.04, but it is not loading CSS.

When I try to enter the installation through the domain (which is connected to VPS's IP), it shows just HTML. I also tried to go to the IP address of my VPS, and CSS loaded.

The domain is connected to my VPS with CloudFlare.

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: I do not get error.

Comment: The problem is that WordPress is not loading CSS

Comment: did you check console logs?